# Unable to export summarized data from Power BI service. File couldn't be created

Tags: powerbi, tableview, export-to-csv

The error message says: File couldn't be created. Executing the Query for the Export Data operation resulted in an error

It is able to export to csv when the we don't change the table view. But, once we personalize the table structure, it gives the above error message.

Please suggest and guide at the earliest.

I expect it should export the data as the data is not that heavy.